# картинку на JProgressBar

Tags: java

Как поставить свою картинку JProgressBar, а именно на полосу загрузки

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: @Духсообщества я хочу сменить полосу progressbar на свою картинку!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8884297/nice-looking-progress-bar-in-java/8886795#8886795